# how to load API on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, api, dll, registry, hook

My intention is to be able to sucessfully load a .dll file that will hook the Windows API. I have researched and tried extensively, without success, any method that would load my .dll file on a 64bit machine running Windows 7. The two solutions that I have tried include loading the path of the .dll into the registry keys:

Computer/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs

or

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs

please don't get me wrong, there are many online resources explaining how to load APIs to the registry, but none of them have worked for me. I apologize if the answer to this question is obvious, I have tried everything I could. Thanks so much for the time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `AppInit_DLLs` mechanism as it is very dangerous and can lead to crashes and loader-lock deadlocks in other applications (see what the great [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/13/6648400.aspx) has to say on the subject).  If you absolutely, positively must use this mechanism then you can **only** call functions in  kernel32.dll.  No runtime calls **at all**.

A better option is to look into using the [detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) library

Comment: Mandrill, thank you very much for the warning! I definitely won't be considering that approach anymore, and I will look up your suggestion on reading what Raymond Chen has to say.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Technet document which might help - [AppInit DLLs in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/install/AppInit-Win7.mspx)

Comment: Thank you very much Stewart for both the help as well as the fast reply! I'll take a thorough look at the link you provided and post back with details! Again, thanks so much!